# WSO2 APIM: Subdomains for different contexts

Tags: nginx, wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have the WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0 deployed and working. Although we are trying to figure out if it is possible to have multiple subdomains for it.

For example:

```
store.domain.com
publisher.domain.com
carbon.domain.com
```

Is this at all possible? We've seen this https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon442/Adding+a+Custom+Proxy+Path, but this is for different applications, we want to do this only with the API Manager.

In front of the API Manager, we are using nginx with reverse proxy. Below, you can find a snippet from nginx to help while understanding the problem.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name store.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl on;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH";#:AES128+EDH";
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000";

    server_name store.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com/self-ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com/self-ssl.key;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/store.log;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://wso2server:9443/store/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

When attempting to access with HTTP (for the store context) all works fine, but as soon as we switch this over to HTTPS this fails with the following error in nginx `upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream` however, we see nothing in API Manager logs.

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards

Comment: you have http instead of https in "proxy_pass http://wso2server:9443/store/" , can you check it. in APIM by default 9443 is https

Comment: Thanks @Jenananthan we've corrected that. Although still no luck. It seems that the APIM backend is rewriting the URL to `wso2server`, which is our HostName in the `carbon.xml` file.

Comment: are you still getting "upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream" error ? have you gone through this blog http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2014/12/configure-wso2-api-manager-with-reverse.html ?

Comment: Yes, I've seen it. And yes we still get the same nginx error. The thing is that we think that the APIM is rewriting the URL to wso2server, which is not a public URL for that reason, it is not able to find it. For now, we've  eliminated the possibility of having subdomains, and kept the context after a base URL, it seems to be the best solution. If we are able to find anything regarding the subdomains I'll let you know. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your issue by one of following methods.

1. Adding proxy_redirect configs to Nginx. So nginx will rewrite all the URLs to proper URL. Please refer the following config segment.

> ```
> proxy_redirect http://wso2server/ http://store.domain.com/;
> ```

2. Also you can achieve the same by adding reverse proxy configurations in API Manager store. To do this Open "repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/conf/site.json" and see the following config section

> "reverseProxy" : {
>               "enabled" : false,    // values true , false , "auto" - will look for  X-Forwarded-* headers
>               "host" : "sample.proxydomain.com", // If reverse proxy do not have a domain name use IP
>               "context":"",
>             //"regContext":"" // Use only if different path is used for registry
>           },